# Control by response content type?

Tags: flurl

I've been handed an API that is *not* pretty ... i.e. it always returns a `200` but `Content-Type: application/pdf` when successful and `Content-Type: application/text` with some json in the body when it is not successful. Does flurl provide any means to control based on the `Content-Type`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the `SendAsync` method which returns the `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` which once I have that I can access the `Content-Type` and all that fun stuff.